# silverlight disable items in combobox

Tags: silverlight

How do I disabled items in a silverlight comobobox

Answer (score 3):

This is a very helpful tutorial: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1a81c5/disablingcombobox-items-in-silverlight-combobox/

In order to prevent the users to select the disabled items using the keyboard I used the following code:

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem" >
   <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsEnabled}"/>
   <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="{Binding IsEnabled}" />
</Style>
```

Answer (score -3):

```
    <ComboBox  Name="ComboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged">
        <ComboBoxItem IsEnabled="True">
            <TextBlock Text="test1"/>
        </ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem IsEnabled="False">
            <TextBlock Text="test2"/>
        </ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem IsEnabled="True">
            <TextBlock Text="test3"/>
        </ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem IsEnabled="True">
            <TextBlock Text="test4"/>
        </ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem IsEnabled="False">
            <TextBlock Text="test1"/>
        </ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
```

Comment: Tahnks for repling but I want the Item to be disabled before the yours clicks the item

Comment: Tahnks for repling but I want the Item to be disabled before the yours clicks the item

Comment: Disabling the combobox items is insufficient. When the combobox items are disabled the user can still use the keyboard to cycle through all items and select any one, even the disabled ones. Working on a solution to that problem myself.